# Running post request with node adding option param and headers, getting pointernullexception

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, server, backend

Here is the code in server.js

```
const https = require('https')
const http = require("http");
const fs = require('fs');

const fileUrl = new URL('file:///Users/someone.computer/Desktop/sampleFile.csv');

const post_data = fs.readFileSync(fileUrl);

const options = {
  host: 'api.thomsonreuters.com',
  // port: 443,
  path: '/permid/match/file',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'x-ag-access-token': 'myToken',
    'x-openmatch-numberOfMatchesPerRecord': 1,
    'x-openmatch-dataType': 'Organization',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  var str = '';
  console.log(res)
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
    console.log("this is chunk = " + chunk)
  });
  res.on("end", function () {
    console.log("this is str = " + str)
  })
})

req.write(post_data);
req.end();
```

I need to use the csv file and run it through permid.org and match my local csv files containing the data to be matched using their API file match functionality.  In their [docs](https://developers.thomsonreuters.com/sites/default/files/PermID%20APIs%20User%20Guide%20_June.pdf) it says I needed to include the parameters and headersas I have included in an object below called `options`.  To read the file I'm using `fs npm package`

when I run `node server.js` I get below in the terminal

```
statusCode: 500
this is chunk = {"error": {"status": {
    "code": "500",
    "errorCode": "Server Error",
    "errorDescription": "java.lang.NullPointerException"
}}}
this is str = {"error": {"status": {
    "code": "500",
    "errorCode": "Server Error",
    "errorDescription": "java.lang.NullPointerException"
}}}
```

Please advise as to what I'm doing wrong - thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using a POST request and setting a content-type; both implying you intend to send data - yet you don't send any data with the request?

Comment: i was sending that csv file wasnt I? can you ensure with my code? can you point out why im not sending a data? I thought I was sending csv file

Comment: or maybe my code is not implicitly sending it on the request? can you elaborate please - thanks much

Comment: You create a variable to hold the file contents, but then do nothing with it. You'll need to set the `options.data` property to `post_data`

Comment: @RandyCasburn I think you are overlooking the line `req.write(post_data);`...

Comment: does it need to be named data? is that a property required in the options object?

Comment: @GelSisaed either `body` or `data`... look at the api of the `https` module and see what it expects

Comment: @PatrickRoberts -  Nevermind - I certainly did mist the `req.write()` statement.

Comment: its giving the same error